# dplyr 'rename' standard evaluation function not working as expected?

Tags: r, dplyr

UPDATE: From comment below on this post, this is now working as expected, without the issues I laid out here.

Below is a toy example of using `rename_` from dplyr.  I was expecting to be able to change the column name back to it's original name using the second example below, but I'm guessing that function argument evaluation rules are somehow preventing it from working the way I think.  There is an easy workaround using the original plyr package `rename` function (as well as using the base package `names` function), but I have a feeling I'm missing a dplyr solution to this.

I have a workaround as shown below, but I'd welcome both a dplyr solution to the second example working as I expect, or an explanation of why I shouldn't expect it to work the way I want it to.

Thank you,
Matt

EDIT: I added an example below using `rename_` to make this work, but is complicated.  I assume if the bug that Hadley refers to below gets fixed, this will work as he shows below.  But until then, my awkward way does, but it is probably better to use the standard `plyr` method.  Also added base R technique at end for example completeness.

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

# dataframe to operate on
dat <- data_frame(a=1, b=1)

# identifier with string of column name in dat
x <- "a"


# Renaming using standard evaluation this way works
dat %>%
    rename_("new" = x)
# Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
# 
#   new b
# 1   1 1


# But changing it back does not
# I expect "a" to be the name, not the identifier x
dat %>%
    rename_("new" = x) %>%
    rename_(x = "new")
# Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
# 
#   x b
# 1 1 1


# This works, but seems really awkward...
dat %>%
    rename_("newname" = x) %>%
    do(do.call(rename_, setNames(list(., "newname"), c(".data", x))))

# Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
# 
#   a b
# 1 1 1


# This works fine
dat %>%
    rename_("new" = x) %>%
    plyr::rename(c("new" = x))
# Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
# 
#   a b
# 1 1 1


# Base R way
datrn <- dat %>%
    rename_("newname" = x)
names(datrn)[names(datrn) == "newname"] = x
datrn
# Source: local data frame [1 x 2]
# 
#   a b
# 1 1 1
```

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, `rename_(dat, .dots = setNames(x, "new"))` now works as expected.

Comment: Further info on this kind of stuff is available in the dplyr vignette on non standard evaluation: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html

Answer (score 16):

There are a few thing that make this painful:

1. `c(x = "new")` is the same as `c("x" = "new")`, and not the opposite
   of `c(new = x)`.
2. You can construct the vector you want with `setNames(x, "new")`,
   but...
3. I forgot to add the `.dots` argument to `rename_` (bug report at
   https://github.com/hadley/dplyr/issues/708) so you can't do:

   ```
   rename_(dat, .dots = setNames(x, "new"))
   ```

   Instead you need to use `do.call`:

   ```
   do.call(rename_, c(list(quote(dat)), list(setNames(x, "new"))))
   ```

Comment: So, I'm trying to make the `do.call` example work, and I'm not getting it to work.  Not sure how to change that to incorporate the `dat` object into that call, as it isn't referenced in the call itself.

Comment: And, in various ways of trying `setNames`, I'm getting the following type of error: `All arguments to rename must be named.FALSE`

Comment: @mpettis that do.call invocation should be a bit better

Comment: I tried that variation and I got `> do.call(rename_, list(dat, setNames(x, "new")))
Error in rename_vars_(names(.data), dots) : 
  All arguments to rename must be named.FALSE`

Comment: This is the `do.call` structure I was able to make work: `do.call(rename_, setNames(list(datrn, "new"), c(".data", x)))`

Answer (score 2):

In my Rstudio, I define:

```
x <- 'myname'
dat <- data.frame(yes=1, no=2)
```

I want to change the variable name from *yes* to *myname*

It doesn't work:

```
rename_(dat, .dots = setNames(x, "yes"))
```

But this works:

```
rename_(dat, .dots = setNames("yes", x))

rename_(dat, .dots = setNames("yes", paste(x) ))
```