# renaming column names with variable

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to rename a specific column with new name which comes as a variable in `dplyr`.

```
newName = paste0('nameY', 2017)
```

What I tried was

```
iris %>% 
    rename(newName = Petal.Length) %>%
    head(2)
```

Which gives

```
Sepal.Length Sepal.Width newName Petal.Width Species
         5.1         3.5     1.4         0.2  setosa
         4.9         3.0     1.4         0.2  setosa
```

I am getting `newName` not `nameY2017` which is normal. So I tried

```
iris %>% 
    rename_(eval(newName) = 'Petal.Length')
```

But then I am getting an error.

> Error: unexpected '=' in "iris %>% rename_(eval(newName) ="

Is there a proper way to do it with `dplyr`?
I know I can do something like

```
names(iris)[3] <- newName
```

But that wouldn't be `dplyr` solution.

Comment: This has been answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520813/r-dplyr-rename-and-select-using-string-variable

Comment: Did you tried `names(iris)[which(names(iris) %in% "newName")] <- paste0('nameY', 2017)`. Is not `dplyr`but it should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit and further information in this post for this [dplyr 'rename' standard evaluation function not working as expected?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26619329/dplyr-rename-standard-evaluation-function-not-working-as-expected)

Your code:

```
newName = paste0('nameY', 2017)
iris %>% 
  rename(newName = Petal.Length) %>%
  head(2)
```

Solution:

```
iris %>% 
  rename_(.dots = setNames("Petal.Length",newName)) %>%
  head(2)
```

Output:

```
  Sepal.Length Sepal.Width nameY2017 Petal.Width Species
1          5.1         3.5       1.4         0.2  setosa
2          4.9         3.0       1.4         0.2  setosa
```